# Can't switch from any state to running state (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 2d-games

I'm learning how to create a simple 2D platformer in Unity. I've been following a tutorial from a youtuber called "Coding in Flow". I've set up all the animations correctly (idle, running, jumping, falling), and after a while of getting to learn how to code in c# for those types of things, i wanted to add a walk movement and animation.

After adding the animation and code, here's what's happening and i can't figure out why:
Everything works, except now for the running movement and animation (i set walking to one button (a/d), and running to two buttons, (a/d + left shift)).
When i do press shift, it activates the movement and animation but only for half a millisecond.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private Animator anim;

    private float dirX = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float walkSpeed = 3f;
    [SerializeField] private float runSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 14f;

    private enum MovementState { idle, walking, running, jumping, falling }

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        // WALKING MOVEMENT

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * walkSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

        // RUNNING MOVEMENT

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Horizontal") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * runSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        // JUMPING MOVEMENT

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }

        UpdateAnimationState();
    }
    
    private void UpdateAnimationState()
    {
        MovementState state;

        // RUNNING AND WALKING AND IDLE ANIMATIONS

        if (dirX > 0f)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                state = MovementState.running;
            }
            else
            {
                state = MovementState.walking;
            }
            sprite.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (dirX < 0f)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                state = MovementState.running;
            }
            else
            {
                state = MovementState.walking;
            }
            sprite.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.idle;
        }

        // JUMPING AND FALLING ANIMATIONS

        if (rb.velocity.y > .1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.jumping;
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.y < -.1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.falling;
        }

        anim.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
    }
}
```

I tried using GetButtonDown instead of GetKeyDown, changing the controls, but i still can't figure out why it only works for a millisecond (i can tell when looking at the animator tab: when i press the two buttons for running, it only works for a millisecond).

I assume it's due to the way i wrote my code considering that i am only a beginner.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) works only in 1 frame when the key is pressed.
To check keys in multiple frames you need to use [Input.GetKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html)
like:

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        state = MovementState.running;
    }
...
```